Ansible Extract JSON Dased Off List
Trying to write a task to parse through the json data (influxdb buckets) to create api tokens for each bucket identified in a the influxdb.yml file where api_token=yes.
Here is the influxdb.yml that list all the items; however influxdb has some internal ones that I don't want to make tokens for.
influxdb_buckets:
  - name: default
    api_token: no
  - name: linux
    api_token: yes
  - name: vmware
    api_token: yes
  - name: elasticsearch
    api_token: yes
  - name: windows
    api_token: yes

The ansible task:
- name: Get bucket IDs
  ansible.builtin.command: "influx bucket list --json"
  register: bucket_list

- name: Buckets ID and Name
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    buckets_ids_names: "{{ bucket_list.stdout | from_json | json_query('[].{id: id, name: name}') }}"


This returns for example
"buckets_ids_names": [
        {
            "id": "f883cd9d1bc409e1",
            "name": "_monitoring"
        },
        {
            "id": "e68eb87555d06949",
            "name": "_tasks"
        },
        {
            "id": "c7ad12c4d667cde8",
            "name": "bucket"
        },
        {
            "id": "0b1f6d500a73f5cf",
            "name": "elasticsearch"
        },
        {
            "id": "e2881de1d38b0938",
            "name": "linux"
        },
        {
            "id": "6d279a8ef3d1a93d",
            "name": "vmware"
        },
        {
            "id": "4d93c36e6dc82f2d",
            "name": "windows-eventlogs"
        },
        {
            "id": "f30aa00ad510fee5",
            "name": "es-windows-performance"
        },
        {
            "id": "2baeba1ff0e2125a",
            "name": "windows-services"
        }
    ]


Now need a way to compare the names in both two and if it is not listed in influxdb.yml then discard it.

Q: "Discard not listed in influxdb_buckets"
A: Get the names and select the attribute name
  names: "{{ influxdb_buckets | map(attribute='name') }}"
  result: "{{ buckets_ids_names | selectattr('name', 'in', names) }}"

gives
  result:
    - {id: 0b1f6d500a73f5cf, name: elasticsearch}
    - {id: e2881de1d38b0938, name: linux}
    - {id: 6d279a8ef3d1a93d, name: vmware}



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  vars:

    influxdb_buckets:
      - {api_token: false, name: default}
      - {api_token: true, name: linux}
      - {api_token: true, name: vmware}
      - {api_token: true, name: elasticsearch}
      - {api_token: true, name: windows}

    buckets_ids_names:
      - {id: f883cd9d1bc409e1, name: _monitoring}
      - {id: e68eb87555d06949, name: _tasks}
      - {id: c7ad12c4d667cde8, name: bucket}
      - {id: 0b1f6d500a73f5cf, name: elasticsearch}
      - {id: e2881de1d38b0938, name: linux}
      - {id: 6d279a8ef3d1a93d, name: vmware}
      - {id: 4d93c36e6dc82f2d, name: windows-eventlogs}
      - {id: f30aa00ad510fee5, name: es-windows-performance}
      - {id: 2baeba1ff0e2125a, name: windows-services}

    names: "{{ influxdb_buckets | map(attribute='name') }}"
    result: "{{ buckets_ids_names | selectattr('name', 'in', names) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result | to_yaml



So if people have the same question, here is how I was able to resolve it:
- name: Get bucket IDs
  ansible.builtin.command: "influx bucket list --json"
  register: bucket_list

- name: Populate buckets_with_api_token_yes
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    bucket_ids_names: "{{ bucket_list.stdout | from_json | json_query('[].{id: id, name: name}') }}"

- name: Populate buckets_with_api_token_yes
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    buckets: "{{ lookup('file', '../../../group_vars/influxdb.yml') | from_yaml }}"

- name: Get bucket
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    filtered_buckets: "{{ buckets.influxdb_buckets | selectattr('api_token', 'equalto', true) | map(attribute='name') | list }}"

- name: Create variable with matching bucket names and ids
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    matching_bucket_names_and_ids: "{{ matching_bucket_names_and_ids | default([]) + [{'name': item.name, 'id': item.id}] }}"
  loop: "{{ bucket_ids_names }}"
  when: item.name in buckets.influxdb_buckets | selectattr('api_token', 'equalto', true) | map(attribute='name') | list

- name: Create authorization tokens
  ansible.builtin.command: "influx auth create -d '{{ item.1 }} write token' --write-bucket '{{ item.0 }}'"
  loop: "{{ matching_bucket_names_and_ids }}"


A little explanation can go a long way.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
